# difference in list creation in python

Tags: python, list, initialization, nested-lists, creation

I am trying to create nested list of arbitruary size N X M

assume N = 3, M = 3
when I create a list like this

```
c = [0 for col in range(N)]   
c = [c for r in range(M)]  
print c
```

and execute

```
c[0][0]=1
```

I get

```
c = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

But when I create a list like this:

```
c = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

and execute

```
c[0][0] = 1
```

I get

```
c = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I am new in python, can somebody give me some idea ?

Comment: You placed the same sublist `c` across the list.

Comment: yeah, but why it is updating 3 values in the first case c[0][0],c[1][0],c[2][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In list comprehension, you are creating a reference to every element in the list. That means that every element will be mutated when only one index is accessed and updated.

```
c = [0 for col in range(3)]
c = [c for r in range(3)]  

c[0][0] = "Test"
```

Output:

```
[['Test', 0, 0], ['Test', 0, 0], ['Test', 0, 0]]
```

Edit:

A nested list of arbitrary size:

```
import random

new_list = [[0 for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))] for b in range(random.randint(1, 10))]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: thanks Ajax, that was quick, how can I create a nested list of arbitruary size during the runtime

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Every list is an object....
In your first case you are creating a list object and referring it with a reference variable 'c'.
So whenever yo change particular element in 'c' it reflects in main list.

i.e.,

## First Case

c = list([0,0,0])
c = list([c,c,c])

so if you change element in one 'c' it reflects in all